# How can we get the index number of an element from pl-sql collection?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I inserted some records of data from a table to a collection type table and then I want to delete some records from the collection that doesn't satisfy a condition.

how can I do that though the only option to delete a record from a pl-sql collection is with DELETE method?

Comment: Use `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column = some_value`

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen ,that table is a pl-sql collection type not a database table, I don't think we can do DML like that you said.Are you sure?

Comment: You need to iterate over all elements, check the condition for each element and then use the [delete](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99961) method to remove those.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ,yes your'e right, I think the only solution is what you said,thank you.

Comment: You might consider using an associative array - [docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#CHDEIDIC). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a associative array named `myCollection` indexed by a `binary_integer` it should look something like this:

```
DECLARE
   i BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN
   i := myCollection.FIRST;
   WHILE (i IS NOT NULL) LOOP
      IF (myCollection(i) ...) THEN
         myCollection.DELETE(i);
      END IF;
      i := myCollection.NEXT(i);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this exact syntax is correct for your database, but you can use a subquery to select the ID's of the items that satisfy your condition.

```
DELETE FROM "Table"
  WHERE "Table"."ID" IN (( -- notice double parentheses
      SELECT "ID" -- this subquery returns the IDs for the rows you want to delete
        FROM "Table" -- which are then tested in the IN () statement
        WHERE "Table"."ConditionField" = 'Condition Satisfied'
    ))
```

Comment: can we do this kind of delete over pl-sql collections? don't we have to use DELETE(i) method for collections?